# Returning a const pointer throws a compile error in Unreal Engine?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am not terribly great at C++ so I am sorry in advance if this is just a silly mistake. I was trying to expose the XMLParser to blueprints in Unreal Engine

Using VS, the code doesn't show any compile errors inline. (i.e. no red lines anywhere) However, when I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
Unrecognized type 'FXmlNode' - type must be a UCLASS, USTRUCT or UENUM
```

The line of code in question:

```
UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
        const FXmlNode* GetRoot();
```

I updated the Build.cs with the XMLParser module and can access the functions inside of the various XML classes. However, I find it odd that the compiler doesn't recognize it. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To be able to use `FXmlNode*` as a return type, you must  forward declare the type or `#include` the .h file that defines the type.

Comment: Is your error related to something like this? https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/c-gameplay-programming/124837-compiler-error-type-must-be-a-uclass-ustruct-or-uenum

Comment: @RSahu I just tried both forward declaring it as well as making sure the include file was present. It still gave the same error.

Comment: @darclander that may be the issue. However, I am unsure at the moment.

Comment: Looking through some similar issues the error might be related to more than just the line you provided. Could you add further information? Do you include XmlNode.h? What is GetRoot()? According to this documentation: https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/XmlParser/FXmlNode/index.html, there is no standard GetRoot() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was rather a simple once I actually thought about it a little bit. The XmlNode class was not a UCLASS type and I can't return a non-U* type inside of Blueprints which was an issue. (Hence why the error makes sense now)

Instead I created another wrapper class for the XmlNode class itself and made it a UCLASS type. From there it was rather easy to wrap the XmlNode class since it mainly was returning Strings and other node references.